# How to interpret the natural spline value in GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, splines

This is a very basic question but I couldn't figure it out. I am using R to predict premium based on current premium.

```
fit <- glm(Premium ~ ns(Primary_Premium,df=2),data = dat, family = 
Gamma(link="log"))
pred <- predict(fit, newdata= dat,type = "response")
b <- data.frame(Primary_Premium = dat$Primary_Premium,ppre = 
ns(dat$Primary_Premium,df=2),Premium = dat$Premium,predicted = pred)
x <- data.frame(Coeff = fit$coefficients)
head(b)
x
```

I got value like these:

```
> head(b)
Primary_Premium    ppre.1     ppre.2 Premium predicted.b
1          950000 0.3408506 -0.1395059  522500    311786.1
2          950000 0.3408506 -0.1395059  300000    311786.1
3          950000 0.3408506 -0.1395059  200000    311786.1
4          950000 0.3408506 -0.1395059  180000    311786.1
5          950000 0.3408506 -0.1395059  140000    311786.1
6          950000 0.3408506 -0.1395059  100000    311786.1

> x
                              Coeff
(Intercept)                  10.7871678
ns(Primary_Premium, df = 2)1  5.7360387
ns(Primary_Premium, df = 2)2  0.6611012
```

My question is, how to use the coefficients and values to build the formula? 
For example,

```
311786.1 = exp(10.7871678 + 5.7360387*0.3408506 + 0.6611012* (-0.1395059)^2)
```

but the results of two sides aren't equal. Anyone who is familiar with natural spline can help me? Thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

```
311786.1 = exp(10.7871678+5.730387*0.3408506+0.6611012* (-0.1395059))
```

Comment: Congratulations for answering your own question! This is absolutely something that we encourage. To make your question and answer more helpful for future readers, it might help to add a bit  of writing to explain what's happened here - [here's our guide on how to write a nice answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)